# Browser calculation error?

Tags: math, browser

My friend stumbled into a strange error (at least I think it is an error). When you multiply a certain number in the console of your browser, 1.4 in my case, then the output is very interesting when you multiply it with 3, 6 and 7. Check these outputs in Firefox:

[image]

In Chrome it is the same as in Firefox, in Edge and IE it's even more interesting, there is the outcome by the multiplication with 6 even more off:

[image]

I googled it but couldn't find any explanation about this error. Does anyone know why the browsers fail at this multiplication?

EDIT: The comments below explain why the number isn't just let's say 4.2 but a heck of a lot numbers which gets a 4.199999999999999. Thanks for referring me to those answers.

However, why does this only happen by 3, 6 and 7 and not with the other numbers? (Maybe at number higher than 10 it will happen to, didn't check that.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 1):

Your friend stumbled across floating point representation of numbers.

Below quote is taken from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21895757/210971

> In most programming languages, floating point numbers are represented
>   a lot like scientific notation: with an exponent and a mantissa (also
>   called the significand). A very simple number, say 9.2, is actually
>   this fraction:
>
> ```
> 5179139571476070 * 2 -49
> ```
>
> Where the exponent is -49 and the mantissa is 5179139571476070. The
>   reason it is impossible to represent some decimal numbers this way is
>   that both the exponent and the mantissa must be integers. In other
>   words, all floats must be an integer multiplied by an integer power of
>   2.